# Apache redirect to Docker port

Tags: docker, apache2, mod-proxy

I have a server running apache2 and it has some applications that are located /var/www/ html

example:

www.server.com/app

www.server.com/app2

In this same server I have Docker running application on port 9090

I would like to type in the browser at url www.server.com/app3 and the request will be redirected to port 9090

I tried this setting on sites-available but don´t working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.com/app3
    ServerAlias /app3
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app3 http://server.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /app3 http://server.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use location in apache config

```
NameVirtualHost         *:80
NameVirtualHost         *:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abrfanet.com
    ServerAlias www.abrfanet.com
    ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com
 ProxyPass / http://container_name:PORT/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://container_name:PORT/
ProxyPass /public !

ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

  <Location />
    ProxyPass          http://container_name:PORT/
    ProxyPassReverse   http://container_name:PORT/
    SetEnv              proxy-sendchunks 1
  </Location>

  <Location /app2/>
    ProxyPass          http://container_name2:PORT2/
    ProxyPassReverse   http://container_name2:PORT2/
    SetEnv              proxy-sendchunks 1
  </Location>
  <Location /app3/>
    ProxyPass          http://container_name3:PORT3/
    ProxyPassReverse   http://container_name3:PORT3/
    SetEnv              proxy-sendchunks 1
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

also i suggest to you , you can use apache in docker its Easier to work

Comment: Thanks for your help Mohammad
Unfortunately it didn't work
When I tried to access the aplication I received this message in the browser

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @VambertoRochaJunior please remove /app3 from ServerName and server alias and also  append / to location , like my code